# Как правильно сделать валидацию формы в javascript?

Tags: javascript

В общем, есть форма. В ней ряд полей.
Как сделать так, чтобы, если данные из поля field1 равные icontype и данные из поля field2 равные 2, выбивало ошибку и не переводило на следующую страницу?

Если не трудно, подскажите, как будет правильно написать такой код:

```
if (elems.field1.value=='icontype' && elems.field2.value==2) {
    showError(elems.vic.parentNode, ' Ошибка. Такая конфигурация не поддерживается.');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код нужно форматировать!
Как-то так:

```
F1: <input type='text' id='field1' /><br />
F2: <input type='text' id='field2' /><br />
<input type='button' value='Check' onclick='valid();' />

function valid(){
  var f1 = document.getElementById('field1');
  var f2 = document.getElementById('field2');

  if(f1.value = 'icontype' && f2.value = 2){
    console.log('Error!');
    return false;
  }

/* Your code here... */
}
```

P. S. Такая жёсткая привязка может аукнутся в будущем, проверено на практике.